JavaScript vs Python Backend React Native
I recently started a project in React Native, and am I very new to React JS and come from a background of Python Flask Web Dev. So far, I have only used JavaScript for the UI and to connect and utilize the Google Maps Geolocation API using React Hooks to get a users location and fetch() to obtain the Geolocation API key. I noticed that if I continue utilizing this method to use all the Google Maps APIs I need in my app, my entire project would be in JavaScript. This isn’t good because I’m not very comfortable with JS so debugging and expanding the project would be difficult and time tasking. So, I am debating whether I want to create a Python API and use flask for my backend rather than JS, connecting and utilizing the APIs with Python instead of JS(which also means I would have to redo the method I use to apply the geolocation API in my app). It would be greatly appreciated if anyone had any advice on what if I should make the switch to Python backend or continue with JS. Thanks!
